# Why sprintf() generates the question mark character, as output?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, embedded, platformio

While working on an embedded project, I noticed that `sprintf()` method for the following code:

```
  char ln2[16];
  sprintf(ln2, "%f Volt", Data[Position].Voltage1);
```

generates the question mark character as output.

The output generated from the code above is:

```
? Volt
```

while the input is declared as `double Voltage1 = 0.0;`

The same issue does not seem to apply while trying to format an integer.
The following works as expected:

```
  char ln1[16];
  sprintf(ln1, "POSITION %d", (Position + 1));
```

and outputs `POSITION 3` where the `Position` is a global variable and declared as `int`.

The structure that actually holds the data is:

```
struct data
{
  int Position;
  double Voltage1;
  double Voltage2;
};
```

All above while using the [C/C++](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) 
and the [Platform.io](https://platformio.org/) extensions both for VS Code.

What is going on wrong here?

Comment: `ln2` is pointing to a *string literal*, which should not be modified. Attempting to do so has an *undefined behavior*.

Comment: There should be hundreds of duplicates. Any canonical ones, anyone?

Comment: Actually it is not this case. Let me post an update

Comment: Did you link with _printf_float? Most probably your "platformio" has some option to link with full version of C library, that does include float printf support, and such support is not included by default. `sprintf(ln1,` is undefined behavior no matter what it outputs. The code may output anything, also a valid output, and still the code is very invalid.

Comment: Your update has the same flaw. Before you fix the UB no definitive answer can be provided.

Comment: C libraries for embedded systems may attempt to reduce code size by not supporting floating point numbers. So the question mark simply means that you haven't enabled the floating point features of `sprintf`.

Comment: BTW, the code should be `char ln2[] = "...............";` That creates an a array of characters that you can legally write to.  (Wow, they're removing spaces even in code snippets. The dots represent space characters.)

Comment: @user3386109 has a very possible explanation. Which compiler/C library are you using?

Comment: @user3386109 I guess this one must be the case

Comment: @OrElse Could be, but to know for sure (and to get help fixing it), the question needs more information about the tools and libraries that you're using.

Comment: @user3386109 There's no need to initialize it with a string literal. Just make sure it's defined as an array. The question was edited 4 minutes ago, and now shows `char ln2[16];`, which should be fine (and works correctly on my system). We still need a [mre]. I'm guessing it's an issue with `*printf` not supporting floating-point by default.

Comment: If my guess is correct (that you have to do something special to enable floating-point in `sprintf`), then  you should be able to reproduce the problem with a simple program that just does `printf("%f\n", 0.0);`. Please try that, and if that prints a question mark, update your question to show a *complete* sample program (should be about 4 lines total). BTW, Visual Studio Code is an editor and should have no effect on the program's behavior. You've probably configured it to invoke the compiler with certain options; you should get the same behavior invoking the compiler directly.

Comment: Also, "embedded" isn't enough information. Since embedded systems vary *a lot*, we likely need to know what embedded system you're targeting and what compiler you're using.

Comment: @KeithThompson Into the spot. The printf("%f\n", 0.0) returns -1

Comment: `printf("%f\n", 0.0)` returning -1 is a different problem. That simply means that `printf` is not supported because there is no `stdout` for `printf` to use. Try `printf("hello")` and I expect the return value will be -1.

Comment: @user3386109 Here we go again. You are right. I should better check for alternatives https://github.com/mpaland/printf

Comment: @OrElse It returned `-1` but did it print anything? You got a question mark from `sprintf`, so I'd expect the same from `printf`. (Since it's an embedded target, maybe you don't have access to `stdout`?)

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might try something like `printf("%ld.%03d\n", (long)Voltage1, (int)(Voltage1 * 1000.0))`. (I have not tested this. Watch out for rounding and off-by-one errors.)

Comment: Avoid buffer overflow: `sprintf(ln2, "%f Volt", Data[Position].Voltage1);` --> `snprintf(ln2, sizeof ln2, "%f Volt", Data[Position].Voltage1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embedded versions of the printf usually do not implement float number handling. You need to let the linker to link the correct version of the function. For example for ARM gcc it will be `-u _printf_float` or/and `-u _scanf_float`

Comment: Just want to add a comment that if you are using an AVR based board (most Arduinos) the compiler options are `-Wl,-u,vfprintf` you need to be using an IDE that supports this like Atmel Studio or PlatformIO. I don't think the Arduino IDE has this ability.

Answer (score 2):

`ln2` points to a string literal.  String literals are read-only, so when you attempt to write to it you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should instead define `ln2` as a character array which is writable.

```
char ln2[16];
```

Comment: Actually it is not this case. Let me post an update

Comment: @OrElse The answer still stands after your change.  You can't write to a string literal.  You got "lucky" that it worked in the case with an `int`.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts sir, but I actually have the same results with char ln2[16];

Comment: @OrElse Then there's something else wrong with your code that you're not showing us.  Please update your question with a [mcve] so others may reproduce your problem.

Comment: Not the cause of the problem, but still an issue anyway. +1

Comment: This answer was made obsolete by a recent edit. The OP apparently has the problem after applying your fix.

Comment: @dbush I would rather say - it is normal in the embedded world. You need to let linker know that you want to print/scan floats and you are ready to sacrifice 10/15kb of FLASH